# send and insert Data-table to sqlserver table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I need to send a `datatable` to `sqlserver2012` and, insert `datatable` into a specific table. How can i do that?

*( i don't want do this work in C# i want to send datatable to sqlserver and do this work in sqlserver)*. I saw similar question, but didn't found my answer.

```
Edit:
into sqlserver i want insert datatable rows into a table.
```

Comment: [Use table valued parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) (From SQL Server 2008 onward)

Comment: Tag with C# but you don't want c#!

Answer (score -1):

**Your point is not clear enough for what is your purpose, you can use the `Update()` method which would perform the operation of updating newly added records to your table, this would implicitly send the table to the sql server and update data**

Answer (score -1):

i think you want to save bulk data from DataTable in sqlserver. please peroform following steps

1) Create custom table value data type in sqlserver 2008 onword
2) create stored procedure with custom table value data type parameter.
3) use following code for set parameter value from code

SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RECORD_TBL", Datatable);